# Group similar consecutive events together in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am new with SQL. I am currently learning using a dataset that has user events ordered by time. For example a sample subset is below -

| EventID | UserID | EventName | Timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | search_event | 2020-01-20 09:42:52 |
| 2 | 1 | search_event | 2020-01-20 09:42:58 |
| 3 | 2 | search_event | 2020-01-20 09:43:27 |
| 4 | 1 | checkout_event | 2020-01-20 09:43:49 |
| 5 | 2 | checkout_event | 2020-01-20 09:43:54 |
| 6 | 2 | search_event | 2020-01-20 09:44:12 |
| 7 | 1 | search_event | 2020-01-20 09:54:21 |
| 8 | 1 | search_event | 2020-01-20 12:45:10 |
| 9 | 1 | search_event | 2020-01-20 12:45:32 |
| 10 | 2 | booking_event | 2020-01-20 12:46:52 |

I would like to count total distinct events in 10 min intervals since the first event occurred.

1. User 1 made a search_event at 09:42:52. For the next 10 mins i.e. till 09:52:52 every search event is not counted for User 1. (i.e. the one at 09:42:58 is omitted in the count)
2. User 2 made a search_event at 09:43:27. Hence till 9:53:27 none of the search_events will be counted for User 2.
3. User 1 made a checkout_event at 09:43:49. Omit counting of all checkout events by User 1 till 09:53:49
4. User 2 made a checkout_event at 09:43:54. Omit counting of all checkout events by User 2 till 09:53:54

Basically the following events are counted - (notified by event_ids)

```
Search - 1,3,7,8
Checkout - 4,5
Booking - 10
```

Output as count -

```
Search 4
Checkout 2
Booking 1
```

The following events are omitted due to time overlap.

```
Event ID 2 - Occurs within 10mins of Event ID 1
Event ID 6 - Occurs within 10mins of Event ID 3
Event ID 9 - Occurs within 10mins of Event ID 8
```

Thank you

Comment: What if you have a series of events over an hour that are 1 or 5 minutes apart?  Are all removed?  Also, tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff no those events are not removed. Basically how I see it is that the 10mins time would be configurable. So instead of 10mins I can have it shorter or longer. But after 10mins (configured time) it counts the event once more and then doesn't count it for the next 10mins. Hope I made sense.

My bad for not providing this clarity before. Also making the edit to keep only Postgres as a tag. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple `not exists` checking existence of the same records within 10 minutes before:

> ```
> with a(EventID, UserID, EventName, ts) as (
>   select 1, 1, 'search_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 09:42:52' union all
>   select 2, 1, 'search_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 09:42:58' union all
>   select 3, 2, 'search_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 09:43:27' union all
>   select 4, 1, 'checkout_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 09:43:49' union all
>   select 5, 2, 'checkout_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 09:43:54' union all
>   select 6, 2, 'search_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 09:44:12' union all
>   select 7, 1, 'search_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 09:54:21' union all
>   select 8, 1, 'search_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 12:45:10' union all
>   select 9, 1, 'search_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 12:45:32' union all
>   select 10, 2, 'booking_event', timestamp '2020-01-20 12:46:52'
> )
> select *
> from a
> where not exists (
>   select null
>   from a as f
>   where f.userid = a.userid
>     and f.eventname = a.eventname
>     and f.ts > a.ts - interval '10' minute
>     and f.ts < a.ts 
> )
> order by eventid
> ```
>
> ```
> eventid | userid | eventname      | ts                 
> ------: | -----: | :------------- | :------------------
>       1 |      1 | search_event   | 2020-01-20 09:42:52
>       3 |      2 | search_event   | 2020-01-20 09:43:27
>       4 |      1 | checkout_event | 2020-01-20 09:43:49
>       5 |      2 | checkout_event | 2020-01-20 09:43:54
>       7 |      1 | search_event   | 2020-01-20 09:54:21
>       8 |      1 | search_event   | 2020-01-20 12:45:10
>      10 |      2 | booking_event  | 2020-01-20 12:46:52
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=0fc7319bb50b4af1e67b02b211a7fef3)*